Techniques to make residential buildings more blast resistant
There are generally two approaches:

First: use stronger materials (e.g. thicker RCC with fibres, go underground, etc).
Second: for any given material, use a superior design.

The First approach is broadly studied in various evaluations. However, I fail to see much about the Second approach.
For example, the photos below claim that partitioning the housing units into smaller columns, with ample gaps in between and below, along tilting some units, shall cause blasts to be less efficient at blowing up walls, as more energy would disperse into air through the gaps (path of least resistance).
However, these photos are from non-credible sources via social media that I came across recently.
Therefore, my questions are:

Is this design's claim correct (and why)?
What is the state of art in blast resistant buildings?




@SolarMike—You're right. I now accepted the answers. There were some good answers that I missed. Thanks for raising this up and apologies for the mess (I also benefited re-seeing the answers, as some of them are still relevant).
